# How to transfer Anaconda env installed on one machine to another? [Both with Ubuntu installed]

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have been using `Anaconda(4.3.23)` on my GuestOS `ubuntu 14.04` which is installed on Vmware on HostOS `windows 8.1`. I have setup an environment in anaconda and have installed many libraries, some of which were very hectic to install (not straight forward pip installs). few libraries had inner dependencies and had to be build together and from their git source.

**Problem**
I am going to use Cloud based VM (Azure GPU instance) to use GPU. but I don't want to get into the hectic installation again as i don't want to waste money on the time it will take me to install all the packages and libraries again

Is there any way to transfer/copy my existing env (which has everything already installed) to the Cloud VM?

Comment: You should be able to do `conda list --export > requirements.txt` and then on your new environment do `conda create --name [env name] --file requirements.txt`

Comment: wouldn't that only work if the packages and libraries are out of the shelf and to be installed from pip?. by your method i will have the name list of packages. and in new env those packages will be installed from pip again. but the problem is i have custom built packages which had dependent configurations with each other

Comment: You might be able to install the dependancies and pip packages via `conda export`. But if you mean installations of other packages (e.g `apt install`) by "hectic installation", I don't think `conda export` might help you. Because, the migration you are trying to do is across different OSs.

Answer (score 8):

From the very end of [this documentation page](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-list.html):

Save packages for future use:

```
conda list --export > package-list.txt
```

Reinstall packages from an export file:

```
conda create -n myenv --file package-list.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if the packages and libraries are out of the shelf and to be installed from pip?. by your method i will have the name list of packages. and in new env those packages will be installed from pip again. but the problem is, i have custom built packages which had inter dependent configurations

Comment: To reinstall, it is "conda **env** create -n myenv --file package-list.txt". By the way, the link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

```
## You can try below approach to move all the package from one machine to other :
## Note : Machine that packages are being moved should be same and python version also should be same



$ pip install conda-pack



# To package an environment:

## Pack environment my_env into my_env.tar.gz

$ conda pack -n my_env

## Pack environment my_env into out_name.tar.gz

$ conda pack -n my_env -o out_name.tar.gz


## Pack environment located at an explicit path into my_env.tar.gz

$ conda pack -p /explicit/path/to/my_env


# After following above approach, you will end up with a tar.gz file. Now to install package from this zip file follow below approach.

## To install the environment:

## Unpack environment into directory `my_env`

$ mkdir -p my_env
$ tar -xzf my_env.tar.gz -C my_env


## Use Python without activating or fixing the prefixes. Most Python
## libraries will work fine, but things that require prefix cleanups
## will fail.

$ ./my_env/bin/python


## Activate the environment. This adds `my_env/bin` to your path

$ source my_env/bin/activate


## Run Python from in the environment

(my_env) $ python


## Cleanup prefixes from in the active environment.
## Note that this command can also be run without activating the environment
## as long as some version of Python is already installed on the machine.

(my_env) $ conda-unpack
```

Comment: This approach is ideal to copy the environment to a machine with limited or without internet connection. [This answer on DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66754/151198) has a bit more details about this approach.

Comment: Just remember if you are using anaconda3 environments on the new machine, you can also copy created out_name.tar.gz file into [whatever directory your anaconda3 folder is located]>anaconda3>envs>[Make a new directory* with your desired name for your environment] and then continue extracting procedure explained above in order to simply activate your new environment by conda like your other conda environments.

Answer (score 3):

---

## If `conda list --export` failes like this ...

Executing `conda list --export > package-list.txt` creates a file which looks like this:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: win-64
_tflow_1100_select=0.0.1=gpu
absl-py=0.5.0=py_0
astor=0.7.1=py_0
...
```

But creating a new environment by executing `conda create -n myenv --file package-list.txt` gives me this error:

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - markdown==2.6.11=py_0
  ...
```

---

## ... then try to use `conda env export`

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9480) execute the following command on your source machine:

```
source activate yourEnvironment
conda env export --no-builds > file.txt
```

On the target machine execute:

```
conda env create --file /path/to/file.txt
```

The file generated by `conda env export` looks a bit different, but it **contains pip packages as well**:

```
name: yourEnvironment
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - absl-py=0.5.0
  ...
  - pip:
    - astroid==2.0.4
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but i don't think it will solve the problem. Wouldn't that only work if the packages and libraries are out of the shelf and can be installed from pip?. by your method i will have the name/version list of the packages. and in new env those packages will be installed from pip again. but the problem is, i have custom built packages which had inter dependent configurations

Answer (score 2):

According to github thread execute the following command on your source machine:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3847

```
source activate yourEnvironment
conda env export --no-builds > environment.yml
```

**On the target machine execute:**

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

The file generated by conda env export looks a bit different, but it contains pip packages as well:

name: yourEnvironment
channels:

- conda-forge
- defaults
  dependencies:
- absl-py=0.5.0
  ...
- pip:

  - astroid==2.0.4
    ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away with copying the whole Anaconda installation to your cloud instance.

Comment: Won't you have issues with libraries compiled for specific kernels? Nevermind, both use Ubuntu, so that should be fine. This is probably your best bet, @Qaisar Rajput

Comment: The correct way would probably be exporting the environment through yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/how-to-clone-python-working-environment-on-another-machine)

you can export your Anaconda environment using:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

In order to recreate it on another machine using:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

You can modify the `environment.yml` as required because some of the python libraries may be obsolete or due to version conflict in future releases.