# Failed to create conda environment ResolvePackageNotFound

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, environment

I was trying to run a yaml provided by a git but got the following error:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - python==3.8.3=cpython_he5300dc_0
  - torchvision==0.8.2=py38_cu101
  - faiss==1.7.1=py38h7b17aaf_0_cpu
  - certifi==2021.10.8=py38h06a4308_2
  - libffi==3.2.1=he1b5a44_1007
  - libgcc-ng==9.3.0=h2828fa1_19
  - setuptools==49.6.0=py38h578d9bd_3
  - pillow==8.3.1=py38h2c7a002_0
  - libedit==3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - libstdcxx-ng==9.3.0=h6de172a_19
  - scikit-image==0.18.1=py38ha9443f7_0
  - ca-certificates==2022.2.1=h06a4308_0
  - matplotlib-base==3.3.4=py38h62a2d02_0
  - libfaiss==1.7.1=hb573701_0_cpu
  - pytorch==1.7.1=py3.8_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0
  - _libgcc_mutex==0.1=conda_forge
  - python-lmdb==1.2.1=py38h2531618_1
```

I'm very new to conda and have no clue how can I fix this. Please help me!! Thanks.

Comment: I'm running on mac

Comment: Anything with "cuda" in the build string means it's not intended for **osx**. Ask the user you got the YAML from if they can give you a more generic YAML. Some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142779/570918 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015738/570918