# How to find the package name for a specific module?

Tags: python, pip

In cases where we have python code, but no instructions about which packages to install via `pip` before running the code, and we run it:

```py
import inception5h

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement inception5h (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for inception5h
```

Is it safe to guess - i.e. try something like `pip install inception5h` or `pip install inception`?

I assume that in absence of specific instructions about which package to install, we are simply guessing, since (I think), any package could theoretically have modules of any name (that is, there could be numerous packages with a module named `inception5h`).

Is this understanding correct? And are there any clever ways of figuring out which package needs to be installed, preferably without guessing?

Comment: Sorry for the noise with closing/reopening. Still, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/7184375/2650249 since its accepted answer should answer yours.

Comment: Do you, by chance have a working installation of this package somewhere (maybe in a different virtual environment or on a different computer)?

Comment: @sinoroc thanks a lot for the help. Actually, I messed up - buried in [this](https://hackernoon.com/deep-dream-with-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-to-build-your-first-deep-dream-experience-f91df601f479) long article is a line that says inception5h is a file (not a package as I had assumed). I will replace the example if there is a better one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update May 2021***

This should nowadays be relatively straightforward with `importlib_metadata.packages_distributions()`.

See the documentation here: [stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#mapping-import-to-distribution-packages) or [external](https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#package-distributions).

---

***Original answer***

That I know of, there is no straightforward (non-guess) way to deduce the name of a (*PyPI*) *distribution package* name when all you have is the name of an *import package* (or *module*). As explained in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461581/11138259) for example (linked by *@hoefling* in the comments to your question).

There is obviously the convention of having in each *distribution package* 1 *top-level* *importable package* (or *module*) with the same name.

So, for example `pip install requests` allows you to write the Python code `import requests`.

But it is just a convention and obviously there are outliers:

- Some have more than 1 *top-level* *importable package*, for example [*setuptools*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/):

  - `pip import setuptools`
  - `import setuptools` and `import pkg_resources`
- Some have different names entirely, for example the project [*PyYAML*](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/):

  - `pip install pyyaml`
  - `import yaml`

In such a case, I think I would probably try to look up the name of the *import package* in a web search engine and hope to find some results leading to the name of the *distribution package*.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check that what library you are installing is correct or wrong on [www.pypi.org](http://www.pypi.org)  all the python modules are available here.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Visit https://pypi.org/(Python Packaging Index) for getting the command for installing the module.
In your case it's `pip install inception`
**In the future for documentation for installing any module in Python, search the module in pypi and copy the installation command**

Comment: I tried what you suggested (`pip install inception`) but still see `import inception5h` giving `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inception5h'`

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.